# Draw an oblique line

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, geometry

Given the width and height of a line in characters, draw it using ascii characters.

## Input

Two integers separated by a space, the first one being the width, the second one being the height.

Example: `5 3`

## Output

An oblique line formed with the characters `/\|_`, that has the width and height given in the input. The characters must be as well distributed as possible (eg as close as possible from a perfect line), any "leftover" characters being placed near the end of the line.

Good output for `5 3`:

```
\_
  \_
    \
```

Bad output for `5 3`:

```
\__
   \
    \
```

## Test cases

`1 1`:

```
\
```

`3 4`:

```
\
|
 \
  \
```

`10 3`:

```
\__
   \__
      \___
```

`4 7`:

```
\
|
 \
 |
  \
  |
   \
```

`-3 3`:

```
  /
 /
/
```

`3 8`:

```
\
|
|
 \
 |
 |
  \
  |
```

`-3 -8`:

```
|
 \
 |
 |
  \
  |
  |
  \
```

`6 2`:

```
_
 \_
   \__
```

`0 2`:

```
|
|
```

`2 0`:

```
__
```

## Clarification

The characters `_` and `|` represent lines between "pixels". As it is obvious for `_` to reprensent the line below the place we put it, it is not that obvious for `|` (placed in the center). Therefore, it must be arbitrarly decided that the line is located on the **right**. This next example thus shows a perfect square:

```
 __
|  |
|  |
 __
```

That being, a line that begins with a `|` is actually 1 character wider, with the first column looking empty and a line beginning with a `_` is actualy 1 character higher, with the first row looking empty.

## Rules

- As usual, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest answer in bytes wins.
- [Standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/42963) are forbidden.

Comment: What do you mean by "well distributed"?

Comment: It's hard to explain, that's why I put a good and a bad example in "output". (I added "as close as possible from a perfect line")

Comment: @SteeveDroz did you see the edits I've made to your monthconcatenation?

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like [this older challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/ascii-art-bresenham-line-drawing), which had the restriction `0 <= y <= x`. There it was required that the output is identical to Bresenham's algorithm. There are some general rules for being a well distributed line, but they are indeed hard to explain.

Comment: Ugh! I thought I was being clever and I missed this one :-( Oh well, my question is a duplicate.